# Genymotion black screen (virtualbox 5.1.24)

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

Genymotion do not start and show black screen with virtualbox 5.1.24. Log messages from `genymotion-player.log`:

```
...
[Genymotion Player] [critical] [AdbReconnect] [error] `adb shell` returns 1
[Genymotion Player] [critical] [AdbReconnect] [error] `adb shell` returns 1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this answer is for virtualbox 5.1.24 only. If you have different version than this answer is not for you.

Regression was introduced in virtualbox 5.1.24 https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16911
It will be fixed in next version but before you can use quick workaround.

1. You need to have 2 virtual devices minimum
2. Start first virtual device
3. Execute `sudo ip link set dev vboxnet0 up` (or `ifconfig vboxnet0 up`)
4. Start second virtual device
5. Second virtual device should work fine

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need w virtual machines:

1. Start the corresponding virtual machine in VirtualBox. You can start it headless.
2. In host OS, run

   sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 up
3. Start your virtual device in Genymotion.